# Convert multiple png to gif as an animation in R

Tags: r, png, gif, animated-gif

I have a bunch of png files in a directory and I want to convert them into a gif (animated) file via R. Can you please advise how to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is some dummy code you can use:

First use the `magick` package for the GIF 
Use the `magrittr` package or the `dplyr` package for the `%>%`

```
library(magick)
library(magrittr)
```

Then list files in the directory, and combine into gif
fps is frames per second

```
list.files(path='/$PATH/', pattern = '*.png', full.names = TRUE) %>% 
        image_read() %>% # reads each path file
        image_join() %>% # joins image
        image_animate(fps=4) %>% # animates, can opt for number of loops
        image_write("FileName.gif") # write to current dir
```

Answer (score 7):

A solution with the `gifski` package:

```
library(gifski)
png_files <- list.files("path/to/your/pngs/", pattern = ".*png$", full.names = TRUE)
gifski(png_files, gif_file = "animation.gif", width = 800, height = 600, delay = 1)
```

The advantage of `gifski` is that the number of colors in the GIF is not limited to 256.

Comment: With several hundred frames, I find that `gifski` is a lot faster than `magick`.